# Blog favicon should get updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, design

Went to the blog and happened to notice that the icon my browser got is the old "sketchy" FN icon.  Should be updated to match the icon the site has now. At the very least, should be "PF", not "FN".

[image: Example icons]

First icon there is the blog, second is the main site, third is meta.

Comment: The [Christianity.SE blog](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/) also shows the old Sketchy theme favicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build. (make sure you do a hard browser refresh)